# Mercurial: Correct an already pushed tag-name

Tags: mercurial

is there any solution to correct an already pushed tag-name? 
I pushed a tag-name with a faulty version-number. It's not terrible problematic, but if there was a way to correct the tag-name, I'd be thankful if you could tell me more. :)

Thanks a lot for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hg tag --remove NAME ...
hg tag NEWNAME ...
hg push
```

or just edit .hgtags (versioned file, which holds all tags definitions), commit and push^ retagging does not rewrite history or alter any changeset